# R code error with nested loop and if statements

Tags: r, if-statement, nested-loops

I have a nested loop using for which goes into a set of if statements. When my id column was sequential (1:6), the code worked fine. When I changed the id column contents to random numbers (1,5,9,11,15,21) the code no longer works and there is a reoccurring error "Error in if (data$death[i] < data$data[j]) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed".

Here is the example of the new data frame and the code used to set up a vector and then to run the nested loop and  if statements. If the id number is sequential 1:6, there are no errors. But when the id is changed to below, the error keeps coming up. Can anyone advise on why this error might be occurring and any suggestions on how to avoid it? Many thanks!

```
id|intervention|death
1|2|0
5|2|1
9|2|0
11|1|1
15|1|0
21|1|0
```

```
test <- c()

for (i in data$id[which(data$intervention == 1)]) {
  for(j in data$id[which(data$intervention == 2)]){
    if (data$death[i] < data$death[j]){
      test <- c(test,-1)}
    else if (data$death[i] > data$death[j]){
      test <- c(test,1)}
    else if(data$death[i]==data$death[j]){
      test <- c(test,0)}
  }
  test  
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Maybe if you explain what you intend to do with this code, you will be able to get a more direct answer. But what appears to be happening is there is no `data$death[i]` when `i` is 11 or 15, for example, because you have just six rows in this dataset...

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your comment. I'm trying to work out wins, losses and draw's which will be allocated via a 1, -1 or 0. The intervention is a treatment or control. So if someone dies on the control its a win to the treatment, if they die on the treatment, its a loss to the treatment, if neither die, its a draw.

Comment: Also I forgot to mention every pair (treatment and control) is compared using the nested loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be easier ways to achieve your goal. This is one fix of the code.

```
data <- data.frame(
  id = c(1, 5, 6, 11, 15, 21),
  intervention = c(2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1),
  death = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0)
)

test <- c()
for (i in data$id[which(data$intervention == 1)]) {
  print(paste0("id = ", i, ": "))
  for (j in data$id[which(data$intervention == 2)]) {
    if (data$death[data$id == i] < data$death[data$id == j]) {
      test <- c(test, -1)
    } else if (data$death[data$id == i] > data$death[data$id == j]) {
      test <- c(test, 1)
    } else if (data$death[data$id == i] == data$death[data$id == j]) {
      test <- c(test, 0)
    }
  }
  print(test)
  test <- c()
}

[1] "id = 11: "
[1] 1 0 1
[1] "id = 15: "
[1]  0 -1  0
[1] "id = 21: "
[1]  0 -1  0
```

Comment: Wow thank you so much. The [data$id == I] was the clincher and worked a treat. Many thanks!!

Comment: I wanted to create a function with the code. However I tried this and it doesn't seem to write to the test vector when I add it to the loop. Any suggestions on how to update the code to allow this? 

first <- function () {
  if(data$death[data$id == i]<data$death[data$id ==j]){
   return (test <- c(test,-1))}
  else if(data$death[data$id == i]>data$death[data$id == j]){
   return (test <- c(test,1))}
  else if(data$death[data$id == i]==data$death[data$id == j]){
   return (test <- c(test,0))}

Comment: It’s difficult to read long code in comments. If you post it as a new question you may have a better chance of getting an answer